# checkboxes checked based on input value

Tags: jquery, html

i have four check-boxes and an input like that

```
<input type="text" value="" class=" windows ">
```

i have this input: 1010

after splitting i have `1, 0, 1, 0`

i want to check if input is 1 then set checkbox checked, when 0 set the  checkboxes unchecked. 
i have tried this:

```
$(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
```

but that making all checkboxes checked!
any ideas please.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Some code that you have that is not working as expected?

Comment: all my checkboxes have the same class, when i use this: $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);      i am getting all checkboxes checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`prop`'s callback function](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function):

```
$(':checkbox').prop('checked', function(index) {
   return +yourArray[index] === 1;
});
```

Comment: perfect solution, but why i do not have to convert string to integer?

Comment: @tery `+` operator in `+yourArray[index]` converts the string into a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the checkboxes and check/uncheck each one based on the 1/0 value.

E.G:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckboxes" />

<script>
    var arrayFromInput = [ 1, 0, 1, 0 ];

    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('myCheckboxes');

    for(var i=0; i<checkBoxes.length; i++)
    {
        if(i > arrayFromInput.length)
        {
            break;
        }

        checkBoxes[i].checked = arrayFromInput[i];
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. When the length of the value of the input is the same as the amount of checkboxes it enables the right ones based on the inputted number.

Because the number `0` is `false` in javascript and other numbers are `true` we can say `.checked = parseInt(val[i])` inside the for loop.

It is advised to restrict the input so not more then 4 characters can be typed and only 0 and 1 are accepted.

```js
$('.input-cb').on('input', function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val.length === $('.target-cb').length) {
    for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
      $('.target-cb').get(i).checked = parseInt(val[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" class="windows input-cb">
<div id="cb-wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" class="windows target-cb">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" class="windows target-cb">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" class="windows target-cb">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" class="windows target-cb">
</div>
```